# How to understand this probability density function with continuous random variable

Tags: density-function, piecewise-pdf

Could anyone help me? I don't want the solution. Instead I'm just looking to understand what this means:

```
x 
2
```

Is this the Binomial Coefficient? How is this related with PDF?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the fraction bar is missing and that you want $\dfrac{x}{2}$. If that is the case, then the $PDF$ integrates to $1$.

Then you can use calculus or just geometric intuition to figure out the expected value.

Comment: Even though you can reason through the geometry, it might be a useful exercise to be formal about the expected value calculation by solving the integral.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it's supposed to be $\frac x2$ and there's been a printing issue. Notice that if that's the case $f(x)$ is non-negative and integrates to 1 and so is a probability distribution.